# Skip Validation on React-Final-Form when "Cancel" Button Clicked

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form

I have a React-Final-Form that validates its form fields.

I would like to **not** invoke validation when a cancel or reset button is clicked. However, if clicking the cancel button click causes an invalid field to render its error message, the *onCancel function* is never called. This happens even if I set the button type to "reset".

If validate doesn't return a change, only then can the *onCancel* function be reached.

```
  handleSubmit(values) { console.log(JSON.stringify(values, 0, 2)) }

  onCancel() { console.log("cancelled!"); }

  render() {
    const onSubmit = async values => { this.handleSubmit(values); };

   return (
     <Form name="form" 
        onSubmit={onSubmit}
        validate={values => {
                  const errors = {};
                  if (!values.username) { errors.username = 'Required' }
                  return errors }}

        render={({handleSubmit}) => (
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <Field name="username">
              {({ input, meta }) => (
                 <input {...input} type="text" placeholder="Username" autoFocus>
                 {meta.error && meta.touched && <span>{meta.error}/span>}                   
              )}
            </Field>

            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            <button type="button" onClick={onCancel}>Cancel</button>
          </form>
        )}/>
  );
```

Comment: Bottom line, to answer the question, please specify how to suspend form validation via react-final-form or some other way outside of the final-form framework.

Comment: It isn't the case in this poster's question, but for those that arrive via Google search: don't forget that a `button` without a `type` attribute automatically has a `submit` type, and will therefore `touch` all fields and show any errors, regardless of what its `onClick` function says. To prevent that, add `type=button`.

Comment: <button type="submit" onClick={() => form.change("btnClicked", "CANCEL"))}>Cancel</button>, followed by in your validate function => if(values.btnClicked !== "CANCEL") {...do something}. This will allow you to bypass the validation as well

Answer (score 1):

The error is being shown because clicking the Cancel button is blurring the field, causing `meta.touched` to become true. It's not "invoking validation", the error was already calculated.

It doesn't make sense to me that the `onCancel` is not getting called. It certainly seems to be when I run this code.

[image: Edit stupefied-feistel-6kn9p]

If you want Cancel to reset the form, you need to call `form.reset()`. Like in [this example](https://final-form.org/docs/react-final-form/examples/record-level-validation).

If you need the errors to not show and *not* reset the form, you'll need to manage that state yourself.

Comment: The original example was simplified too much and the issue doesn't present. I think there was a side effect with some logic elsewhere that causes the problem. Thanks for the working example.

Answer (score 1):

I just spend hours trying to debug a similar issue. Turns out I just needed to update my styling:

- final-form runs validation onBlur
- onBlur happens before onClick, so when you click the button - first there is a blur event, then there should have been a click event (but there was never a click event)
- During the onBlur, the validation message gets rendered, causing the button to shift down.
- Then the click happens, but it's not clicking the button because the button  moved

Comment: And how did you overcome this issue?

Answer (score -1):

I have faced the similar issue. 
Found this answer related - https://stackoverflow.com/a/74744099/10116675 
Resolution - My cancel button is shifting downward due to the error message, So I have fixed the height of the text input so that it doesn't shift the cancel button.
Now it is working fine.